# Python 3.7 supports which swig version?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using Swig 4.0.2 and using both the python versions 3.7 and 3.4 where swig 4.0.2 is working on python 3.7 but not on python 3.4, can I know swig 4.0.2 supports which version of python or python 3.7 and python 3.4 supports which version of swig?
swig version which supports both python3.4 and the latest version?

for python 3.4 with swig version 4.0.2, I am getting **"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Application_swiginit'"**
but,
it works fine for swig 4.0.2 on python 3.7

Comment: Python 3.4 introduced unicode by changing signatures in the Python C API, which is a terrible way. For this reason, I strongly recommend not to use Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [support](http://www.swig.org/Release/RELEASENOTES)

SWIG 4.0.0 Python version required is now 2.7, 3.2-3.7 are the only
other versions supported.
SWIG 4.0.1 Adds python 3.8